# Mark Logic's cloud formation template not working in eu-west-1 region

Tags: aws-cloudformation, marklogic

I want to install MarkLogic solution in AWS eu-west-1 region using cloud formation template available in http://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws but the stack fails to create launch configuration.

I have downloaded the cloud formation template from the link http://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws and created a AWS cloud formation stack from "mlcluster.template" which is available in the above link but the stake failed during launch configuration set up. Not able to fix the template. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have any error message while stake fail?

Comment: +100  Using either the CLI or the AWS Console,  copy ALL the cloudformation "Events" and post here.  Without those your question is as answerable as "Why doesn't my car work"  
Although in this case I do have 'educated guesses' but to mis-quote a saying "Its best to be thought a fool then to open opens mouth and remove all doubt"

Comment: The AWS CLI is a very good tool to get configured and used to useing.
To get all the cloudformation events for a stack use the command line:

aws cloudformation  describe-stack-events  --stack-name  "Insert your stack name here"

Follow AWS documentation on "aws cli" until you can get useful output from the above, substituting "Insert your stack name here" with your actual stack name.

Answer (score 1):

Problem got fixed. It is a configuration mistake.
For the IAM role parameter in AWS cloud formation stack I have to provide only the IAM name and not the entire ARN. Initially I provided the IAM  ARN and it probably confused the resource name while creating an Auto Scaling Launch Configuration.